# NMinimize is not returning values

Tags: mathematical-optimization, list-manipulation

I am new to Mathematica. What is the mistake I am making in the following code snippet?

```
NMinimize[{y, 
  x*Norm[Array[c1, 10], Infinty] - Norm[Array[c1, 10], Infinty]^2 - 
     y <= 0 && 
   x*Norm[Array[d1, 10], Infinty] - Norm[Array[d1, 10], Infinty]^2 - 
     y <= 0 && 0 <= x <= 1 && 
   And @@ Table[-1 <= c1[i] <= 1, {i, 1, 10}] && 
   And @@ Table[-1 <= d1[i] <= 1, {i, 1, 10}]}, 
 Flatten[{Array[c1, 10], Array[d1, 10], x, y}], 
 Method -> {"SimulatedAnnealing"}, MaxIterations -> 1000]
```

Comment: `Infinty` is not spelled correctly. It should be `Infinity` or the symbol `\[Infinity]` or `∞`. The incorrect spelling of `Infinty` should also be highlighted in blue in your notebook, making it somewhat obvious that it's not defined.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This is the first time I am using the notebook. Still figuring out how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us put `z=Norm[Array[c1, 10], Infinity]` and `t=Norm[Array[d1, 10], Infinity]`. These variables satisfy `z >= 0 && z <= 1` and `0<= t && t <= 1`, so (four variables instead of 22 variables)

```
NMinimize[{y, x*z - z^2 - y <= 0 && x*t - t^2 - y <= 0 && 0 <= x <= 1 && z >= 0 &&
z <= 1 && t >= 0 && t <= 1},{x, y, z, t}, Method -> {"SimulatedAnnealing"},MaxIterations -> 1000]
```

> `{-1., {x -> 1.2904*10^-9, y -> -1., z -> 1., t -> 1.}}`

I leave the rest on your own.